# Scale buttons in in widget

Tags: android, android-layout, widget

I want to create a widget which has number of buttons which will be scaled horizontally when screen size is changed. Can I do it with single layout.xml?

I tried to illustrate it with the image below :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it by setting `android:layout_weight=""` tag in `LinearLayout`. See the below example.

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             >
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/crop"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/crop_drawable" >
            </Button>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/rotate"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/rotate_drawable" >
            </Button>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/auto_correct"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/autocorrect_drawable" >
            </Button>          

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/add_colors"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/addcolor_drawable" >
            </Button>            

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/adjust_saturation"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/adjustsaturation_drawable" >
            </Button>          

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/photo_filter"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/photofilter_drawable" >
            </Button>
        </LinearLayout>
```

In the above example, there are 6 `Buttons` which will accommodate the whole screen exactly of same size irrespective of the Screen size.

Comment: you have enough space to show all button then way should have gave fix height can you please let me know about it?

Comment: @Haresh:setting fixed height of `Button` is just an example my friend.But I guess setting  it to `wrap_content` will give inconsistent height for all `Button` as `Button` height will increase as per its content size.

Answer (score 1):

```
// try this way hope this will help you...
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button1"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button2"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button3"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button4"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```